# SVG <feGaussianBlur> pixelated in dark background

Tags: svg

I'm trying to blur the `rect` element in the svg but seems its pixelated in dark background.

[image].

How can i make smooth blur effect?

Comment: Can you provide example svg? I'm not seeing any pixelation in this test: http://jsfiddle.net/88xwy9Lz/

Comment: sorry for late response plz check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fekkyDev/88xwy9Lz/1/

Comment: When i use this fill color "#212121"

Comment: It looks fine to me. maybe you want a different blur filter besides gaussian? Or try lowering the `stdDeviation`

Comment: Is there any other than this ? please let me know

Comment: No, I am confused. Try playing around with different values for `in` attribute (instead of just `SourceGraphic`) : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/in

Comment: let me try Anthony :)

Comment: Is this firefox/windows? Because yes that's often pixelated/banded with low contrast colors - the good news is that it's the only browser with that problem

Comment: @MichaelMullany Its with google chrome. But any how i have solved this issues by giving some opacity to the element. http://jsfiddle.net/fekkyDev/88xwy9Lz/3/